# Database based table with manually added column - maintaining values positions

Tags: sql-server, excel

Let's consider simple Excel table associated with SQL Server's table:

```
ID    some_data
0     a
1     b
2     c
```

I'd like to extend it with manually added column (not present in SQL Server's table):

```
ID    some_data   my_column
0     a           some_data_for_0
1     b           some_data_for_1
2     c           some_data_for_2
```

However, when source data are changed (rows inserted / deleted / updated) the relation between my_column and ID column is not preserved. For example, when new row (3, d) is added:

```
ID    some_data   my_column
0     a           some_data_for_0
1     b           some_data_for_1
2     c           
3     d           some_data_for_2
```

Is there any Excel built-in solution that would allow me to specify how my_column rows should be ordered in relation to ID column or do I need to implement it by myself using VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an ORDER BY clause in your SQL statement, but even that's not very reliable. The only reliable way to do this is store your additional data in its own table and use a formula to relate it to the SQL data.

On a separate worksheet, put

```
ID    my_column
0     some_data_for_0
1     some_data_for_1
2     some_data_for_2
```

Now in a column adjacent to the SQL data, put

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP([@ID],tblAddtlInfo,2,FALSE),"")
```

However the SQL data is sorted, the additional info will be in the right row. This assumes you made your additional info list into a table and named it tblAddtlInfo.

If you want to get fancy, you can write some code in the Change event that looks for non-formulas in the extra column. If the formula gets over written, then grab the new data, add it to (or update) your additional info table, and restore the formula. Then you can type the data in the row, but maintain the integrity by moving it to a different table.